# Unable to compile/run native Xamarin project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xamarin, rider

Today was my first day at work as a "Junior Xamarin Mobile Developer" and the whole day I was trying to get the project to compile.

Question: I need help with compiling a Xamarin project (not forms but native UI)

Visual Studio: After the whole day I left it with problem (possibly more, time will tell) I need to get ASP.Net re-added to the project.
Nuget - Incompatible versions so I tried to add it to references - had no luck with that it may have been the wrong DLL - not sure, did some more stuff but that's mainly it 
(normal projects work on VS). 
Anyways, where could I download these?[image]

Rider EAP - Sadly it looks like it isn't quite there (in terms of Xamarin) it uses some files from Visual Studio installation and has some problem with paths (error points to some XML type document though, even the IDE doesn't recommend to edit it). So long story short - it can't even build empty projects.

Xamarin Studio (based on mono) - Windows version, aside from stupid installation, it has only Xamarin forms integrated and whenever I open the actual project(the one that i need) it says that I need to install "xamarin.android" - I have no idea how to do it, though I haven't looked into it too much.

Any kind of assistance is appreciated.

Comment: which version(s) of visual studio have you tried it with? don't know what AspNet and SignalR stuff is doing in a Xamarin project .. seem like something else it not building. What about asking your colleagues?

Comment: "Where can you download these?" Would be a great thing for you as a junior developer to investigate. For example, a quick google search on these class names shows that they are inside "SignalR". Thus your project is most likely not restoring the SignalR package and these errors are thrown. Now your task is to include a compatible version of SignalR to your project. There's one on the Xamarin component store specifically: https://components.xamarin.com/view/signalr However I would look at your `.csproj` to see what version and where it's coming from first.

Comment: Ive tryed it with the newest version

@JonDouglas I litrely downloaded form the same place and it threw me an error, but it worked yesterday... wft?!??! anyways, after fixing this one, messing with proguard and paths, and other stuff i managed to get it running